# How to test AsyncTask using Robolectric?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-asynctask, robolectric

I use [Android-DDP](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-DDP/) library in my application. This library implements the `Distributed Data Protocol`.

I would like to implement some integration tests, in which I don't want to mock the `DDP-client`. I've setup the backend instance on the same machine, so I don't worry about network issues.

I started with such test structure:

```
@Inject
Meteor meteor;

@Test
public void testSendMessage() throws Exception {
    final Object[] params = new Object[]{"example params"};//some params are build here.

    final Result result = Result.empty(); //my class for tests;
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    meteor.call("send_message", params, new ResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            result.setSucess(result);
            latch.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String error, String reason, String details) {
            result.setError(error, reason, details);
            latch.countDown();
        }
    });
    latch.await(); // here we block the main thread, and callback will not be called because of it.

    //here goes some assertions, but they will never call.
}
```

But the callback was never called. After a small investigation, I've found that under the hood, **`ddp-client` uses `AsyncTask`** to perform background operation and to deliver callbacks to the client code.

Since **`AsyncTask.onPostExecute` is always called on the `main thread`** I am not able to get call from callback: **Tests blocks the `main thread`** until the callback is called, but callback is never called because `AsyncTask.onPostExecute` is called on the `main thread` (which is blocked by tests)

So, to solve the problem I need to run `tests` or `AsyncTask.onPostExecute` in different threads, or somehow not to block the thread to test the result. Is that possible to do?

Answer (score -1):

First: Don't use AsyncTask

Second: Just see this: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/8b9af4c1f5dec90c07d2532587df48188e9f2c68/shadows/framework/src/main/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowAsyncTask.java

Comment: I know, about AsyncTask issues, but it was from the third-party library.

Comment: I do not want to be rude, but you should change third-party library. But if you can't you can use ShadowAsyncTask from github link which I added in my post

Comment: @MasterDisaster: You didn't link ShadowAsyncTask, you linked to ShadowAsyncTaskTest.